# How to clear react tags input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In `react-tag-autocomplete` lib, need to add manual suggestions.
So, I created new component called `ReactTagsSuggestions` for suggestions list.

How can I clear the input field of `ReactTags`

```
<ReactTags
  id="form-share"
  tags={selectedTags}
  // suggestions={tagSuggestions}
  handleAddition={this.props.handleAddition}
  handleDelete={this.props.handleDelete}
  placeholder={this.props.tags.length ? '' : tr('Share with users, groups, and channels')}
  tagComponent={this.selectedTags}
  handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
  autofocus={false}
/>
<ReactTagsSuggestions
  suggestionList={tagSuggestions}
  showSuggestions={tagSuggestions.length > 0}
  checkToShare={this.props.checkToShare}
/>
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. They haven't exposed the 'state' variable 'query' which is set to input value when the component renders

Answer (score 0):

How about if you create a function like this

```
handleDelete = () => {
  this.setState({ tags: [] })
}
```

and pass this to the ReactTags component

```
<ReactTags
.
.
handleDelete={ this.handleDelete }
/>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

To clean the input field of `ReactTags` you can reset the `selectedTags` to an empty array:

```
clearTag() {
  this.setState({ selectedTags: [] });
}

// Call the clearTag somwhere in your app
<button type="button" onClick={this.clearTag}>Clear tags</button>
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tags-v9mft

Answer (score 0):

It is too late, but may be it will be useful to others. I think you mean clearing input value instead of tags. Here is solution with `useState` and `inputValue` prop of `ReactTags`

```js
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
```

```js
<ReactTags
    inputValue={inputValue}
    handleAddition={(...args) => {
        myHandleAddition(args);
        setInputValue('');
    }}
    handleInputChange={(tag) => {
        if (tag.slice(-1) === ' ') {
            myHandleAddition([{ id: tag, text: tag }]);
            setInputValue('');
        } else {
            setInputValue(tag);
        }
    }}
/>
```